# How do I do a check before every read and write of a variable, c++, access control

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, access-control

I am trying to do a check whenever a value is written or read to while in debug mode, to cache data races and other threadding errors before shipping. This system is only intended for debug mode and should only work as a info gathering system, so no overhead in shipping builds.

Sudo code:

```cpp
template<T>
struct Resource
{
    /*
    Here I need to somehow do a check on all reads and writes?
    How would this class look if it just where to print "read" and "write",
    on their corresponding actions, and is this even possible?

    Edit: The resource class works like wrapper of another type,
    this means the it should also function as so. This can be achieved
    by overriding the &operator.

    Maybe there is something else that can be overwritten in order
    to intercept writes?
    */

    explicit operator T&() { return resource; }
}

class SomeType()
{
public:
    uint32_t GetSomething();
    uint32_t somethingElse;
}

Resource<SomeType> resource1;
Resource<SomeType> resource2;
Resource<SomeType> resource3;

AccessPolicy accessPolicy;
accessPolicy.AddResource(resource1, EAccessPolicy::Read);
accessPolicy.AddResource(resource2, EAccessPolicy::Write);

Task task = Task(&ExampleTask, accessPolicy);

static void ExampleTask()
{
    auto something = resource1.GetSomething(); // Allowed

    resource2 = SomeClass(); // Allowed
    resource2.somethingElse = 4;

    resource3.GetSomething(); // Unauthorized access assert
}
```

Comment: Is `RenderFrameTask` and `ExampleTask` meant to be same thing?

Comment: It would be easier to use thread sanitizer or something similar.

Comment: If you put `get` and `set` methods inline in your class declaration then these should incur no overhead in release builds.  You can `#ifdef` out any code used in debug builds to count or monitor accesses.

Comment: @PaulSanders So you would do Resource.Set() to set? Is it not posible to do someting with operator overrides?

Comment: Not really.  It's certainly not idiomatic, and what would be the advantage?

Comment: @PaulSanders It would just be for cleaner API.

Comment: If you think that, you should add example code to your question to demonstrate exactly what you mean.

Comment: @PaulSanders I changed my example a bit; ideally the Resource class should just be a wrapper around another type that adds access restrictions to the type, for thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
template<T>
struct Resource
{
    Resource(const T &value) { v = value; }
    T & GetSomething(Task & task) {
        if (task.is_allowed(EAccessPolicy::Read, this)) {
            std::cout << "read" << std::endl;
            return v;
        } else {
            // error
        }
    }
    void SetSomething(Task & task, const T & t) {
        if (task.is_allowed(EAccessPolicy::Write, this)) {
            std::cout << "write" << std::endl;
            v = t;
        } else {
            // error
        }
    }
private:
    T v;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about the actual checking, I just want some way of getting notified before every read/write. I edited my example to show what i mean by this.